# Add a new repository to software sources

Tags: apt, repository, software-sources

I tried to add a new repository to software sources, but "add source" button is unavailable. I can't click on it.

I also tried to add a new software source from the terminal, but it didn't work.

```
sudo‬‬ ‫‪add-apt-repository‬‬ ‫‪ppa:n-muench/burg‬‬  
s‫‪udo‬‬: command not found
```

I also tried these commands:

```
‫‪sudo‬‬ ‫‪add-apt-repository‬‬ ‫‪deb‬‬ ‫‪http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/burg/ubuntu‬‬ natty‬‬ ‫‪main‬‬  
sudo‬‬: command not found
```

Comment: Don't put spaces before command.

Comment: Also, the syntax is following: sudo command arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the software center and go to *Edit* -> *Software Sources* menu. 
A popup window will open. Go to the *Other Software* tab and click the Add button at the bottom left corner. Copy/paste this line `ppa:n-muench/burg‬‬` in the *APT line* text box and click the *Add Source* button.

See screenshot below:

[image]

In 18.04 and later open Ubuntu Software and select *Software & Updates* from the dropdown menu in the upper left corner of the desktop. A *Software & Updates* window will open. Select the *Other Software* tab, and click the *Add* button at the bottom left corner. Copy/paste this line `ppa:n-muench/burg‬‬` in the *APT line* text entry box as shown in the above screenshot and click the *Add Source* button.

[image]

After that update your software sources by running this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: it's working although i've tried it and not working then.

Comment: Which application are you trying to install? Are you getting any errors or anything when you try to install it?

Comment: I tried to insatall app called"addad" from ‫‪"ppa:ahmed-linuxawy/ppas‬‬" but i can't add this source can you help me with this?

Comment: I can't add any other source execpt "ppa:n-muench/burg" I don't know why

Comment: What happens when you follow the same procedure as above? I mean, do you get any errors? Are there any inactive buttons..

Comment: yes the button "add source" is inactive i can't click on it

Comment: Try closing the software center then opening it again. If that doesn't work, you can try restarting the machine.

Comment: i will do. then i will tell you what happened.